# What is a good image chooser in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I am looking for a nice image chooser in jQuery. Ext has a nice one [here](http://extjs.com/deploy/ext/docs/index.html) (under Examples and Demos -> Views -> Image Chooser). Is there something like this for jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Extjs actually has adapters for jquery, prototype and yui. This would effectively turn Ext into a jquery add-on. So, with this in mind, you could just slot in the jquery adapter and use the Ext image chooser code. This is a recent discussion on using Ext with jquery: http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=69340